# In this case, why must $p$ divide $|G/N|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading the proposition on page 102 of Dummit and Foote's Algebra, 3rd edition. Could someone explain why $p$ divides $|G/N|$ on the highlighted line?

> **Proposition 21.**
>   If $G$ is a finite abelian group and $p$ is a prime dividing $|G|$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.
>
> *Proof:*
>   The proof proceeds by induction on $|G|$, namely, we assume the result is valid for every group whose order is strictly smaller than the order of $G$ and then prove the result valid for $G$ (this is sometimes referred to as *complete* induction).
>   Since $|G| > 1$, there is an element $x \in G$ with $x \neq 1$.
>   If $|G| = p$ then $x$ has order $p$ by Lagrange’s Theorem and we are done.
>   We may therefore assume $|G| > p$.
>
> Suppose $p$ divides $|x|$ and write $|x| = pn$.
>   By Proposition 2.5(3), $|x^n| = p$, and again we have an element of order $p$.
>   We may therefore assume $p$ does not divides $|x|$.
>
> Let $N = \langle x \rangle$.
>   Since $G$ is abelian, $N \trianglelefteq G$.
>   By Lagrange’s Theorem, $|G/N| = |G|/|N|$ and since $N \neq 1$, $|G/N| < |G|$.
>   Since $p$ does not divide $|N|$, **we must have $p \mid |G/N|$**.
>   We can now apply the induction assumption to the smaller group $G/N$ to conclude it contains an element $\bar{y} = yN$, of order $p$.
>   Since $y \notin N$ ($\bar{y} \neq \bar{1}$) but $y^p \in N$ ($\bar{y}^p = \bar{1}$) we must have $\langle y^p \rangle \neq \langle y \rangle$, that is, $|y^p| < |y|$.
>   Proposition 2.5(2) implies $p \mid |y|$.
>   We are now in the situation described in the preceding paragraph, so that argument again produces an element of order $p$.
>   The induction is complete.
>
> (Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlxUF.jpg).)

Comment: Refer page 6 point number (8). As stated in the answer below, it is known as Euclid's Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vert G \vert = \vert G/N \vert \vert N \vert; \tag 1$

with

$p \mid \vert G \vert, \tag 2$

we must have

$p \mid \vert G/N \vert \vert N \vert; \tag 3$

since $p$ is prime, it obeys the general law known as [Euclid
's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma):

$p \mid ab \Longrightarrow [p \mid a] \vee [p \mid b]; \tag 4$

applying this to (3) with $p \not \mid \vert N \vert$ immediately yields

$p \mid \vert G/N \vert. \tag 5$

***Note Added in Edit, Saturday 18 August 2018 1:43 PM PST:***  Thanks to Chris Custer for pointing out that the "general law" to which I referred above is known as [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma). ***End of Note.***

Comment: The 'general law' is also known as Euclid's lemma...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p \mid |G|$ on the other side $p \nmid |N|$ this means that when we divide $|G|$ by $|N|$ the $p$ factor in $|G|$ doesn't change and thus it can't vanish.